# Get dropdown values through Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code in PoweerShell script:-

```
$options = @{
    "A"="a"
    "B"="b"
}

$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Choose an option"; Options=$options; Tooltip="Choose one."}
    )
    Title = "Option selector"
    Description = "Choose the right option."
    Width = 300
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
}

Read-Variable @props
```

I need to get selected dropdown values. However, it is showing **ok** or **cancel** result when I click on **ok** and **cancel** button in dialog box. I have tried `$props.Parameters.Value` as well it is showing the dropdown values but not the selected value everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check `$selectedOption` value after you execute the script.

That's were the value of what user selected is stored.

Your parameters contain:

```
{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Choose an option"; Options=$options; Tooltip="Choose one."}
```

Look at the part `Name="selectedOption"`. That means that your value will be stored in `$selectedOption` variable.

And you should only process if `$result` returns `ok`, like that:

$options = @{
"A"="a"
"B"="b"
}

```
$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Choose an option"; Options=$options; Tooltip="Choose one."}
    )
    Title = "Option selector"
    Description = "Choose the right option."
    Width = 300
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
}

$result = Read-Variable @props

if($result -eq "ok") 
{
    $selectedOption
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code to get value like this.

```
$options = @{
"A"="a"
"B"="b"
}

$props = @{
Parameters = @(
    @{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Choose an option"; Options=$options; Tooltip="Choose one."}
)
Title = "Option selector"
Description = "Choose the right option."
Width = 300
Height = 300
ShowHints = $true
}

Read-Variable @props
$selectedOption
```